# create new variables in a dataframe from existing variables using lists of names

Tags: r, dataframe

I was wondering if there was a way to construction a function to do the following:

Original dataframe, df:

```
Obs Col1    Col2
1   Y       NA
2   NA      Y
3   Y       Y
```

Modified dataframe, df:

```
Obs Col1 Col2 Col1_YN Col2_YN
1   Y    NA   “Yes”   “No”
2   NA   Y    “No     “Yes”
3   Y    Y    “Yes”   “Yes”
```

The following code works just fine to create the new variables but I have lots of original columns with this structure and the “Yes” “No” format works better when constructing tables.

```
df$Col1_YN <- as.factor(ifelse(is.na(df$Col1), “No”, “Yes”))
df$Col2_YN <- as.factor(ifelse(is.na(df$Col2), “No”, “Yes”))
```

I was thinking along the lines of defining lists of input and output columns to be passed to a function, or using lapply but haven’t figured out how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `across` to loop over the columns and create the new columns by modifying the `.names`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% 
   mutate(across(-Obs,  
   ~ case_when(. %in% "Y" ~ "Yes", TRUE ~ "No"), .names = "{.col}_YN"))
```

-output

```
df1
  Obs Col1 Col2 Col1_YN Col2_YN
1   1    Y <NA>     Yes      No
2   2 <NA>    Y      No     Yes
3   3    Y    Y     Yes     Yes
```

---

If we want to use `lapply`, loop over the columns of interest, apply the `ifelse` and assign it back to new columns by creating a vector of new names with `paste`

```
df[paste0(names(df)[-1], "_YN")] <- 
   lapply(df[-1], \(x) ifelse(is.na(x), "No", "Yes"))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Obs = 1:3, Col1 = c("Y", NA, "Y"), Col2 = c(NA, 
"Y", "Y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Is there a way to define a list of input columns for ".names" in your answer.  Ex: Initial column names: "Tobacco", "Alcohol", "Fentanyl" etc.  with new output columns as "Tobacco_YN", "Alcohol_YN", "Fentanyl_YN" etc.?

Comment: @B.Koch it should be mentioned in `across` i.e. `across(c(Tobacco, Alcohol, Fentanyl), ~ case_when(. %in% "Y" ~ "Yes", TRUE ~ "No"), .names = "{.col}_YN"))`